# python higher order functions: how do i read the code step by step?

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

I am currently trying to interpret the code but i cant seem to visualise it even when i use python tutor.

```
def two(f):
    return lambda x: f(f(x))

def three(f):
    return lambda x: f(f(f(x)))

print(three(two(lambda x: x+5))(2))
print(three(two)(lambda x: x+5)(2))
```

For the first print output, I interpreted it this way:
`two(two(two(x+5))) = (x + 5 + 5) + (5 + 5) + (5 + 5) = 32`

Did I interpret it correctly?

Also, I don't really know how to interpret the second print output.

Comment: It might help to use more temporary variables to hold the results of things like `three(two)`, and to rewrite the code using `def` statements instead of lambda expressions to bind the functions to names. Until you get used to this kind of functional approach, the large nested expressions can be a bit overwhelming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`two(f)` returns a function that applies `f` twice, and `three(f)` returns a function that applies `f` three times.

If `f` is a function that adds 5, then `three(two(f))` is a function that adds 5 six times (3 * 2 = 6).  `three(two(f))(2) == 32`, so you got the right answer, but I think you got it the wrong way.

`three(two)`, however, is a function that applies `two` three times, so `three(two)(f) == two(two(two(f)))`.  `two(f)` adds 5 two times.  `two(two(f))` adds 5 four times.  `two(two(two(f))))` adds 5 eight times, so `three(two)(f)(2)` is 2 + 5 * 8 = 42.

Functions like these are actually a very important part of the development of computing.  They are known as [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals), and this question demonstrates how to do multiplication and exponentiation with them.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, `two()` generates a function that calls your `x+5` two times, and `three()` generates a function that will call that first function three times. This gives means your lambda is called three times two = six times.

In the second case, the `three()` function will call the `two()` function three times, so the result is rather: `two(two(two(f)))(x)`, which means your lambda is called 2 * 2 * 2 == 8 times, and the result is 42.